# Segmentation fault 11 when passing a capture block to a DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I am getting a Segmentation fault on both Swift 4 and Swift 4.2 on a capture block for a DispatchQueue.

I am trying to provide a capture block to the escaping parameter of a DispatchQueue to guarantee that the object passed to the called closure is alive when it will be called.

The code looks something like this:

```
import Foundation

struct Response {
    let outcome: String?
}

enum NotEvenError: Error {
    case notEven
}

struct IsEvenService {
    typealias SuccessCallback = (Response) -> Void
    typealias FailureCallback = (Error?) -> Void

    func perform(success: @escaping SuccessCallback, failure: @escaping FailureCallback) {
        let number = Int.random(in: 0 ... 10)
        if number%2 == 0 {
            let outcome = Response(outcome: "it is")
            success(outcome)
        } else {
            failure(NotEvenError.notEven)
        }
    }
}

func runTest(success: @escaping (Response) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let service = IsEvenService()
    service.perform(success: { (response) in
        if response.outcome != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [resp = response] in
                success(resp)
            }
        }
    },
                    failure: { (error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [err = error] in
            failure(err)
        }
    })
}
```

The problematic part is the following:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [err = error] in
    failure(err)
}
```

This is a sample file that can be easily verified with a swiftc call in the command line.

Here is the outcome:

```
Apple Swift version 4.2 (swiftlang-1000.11.37.1 clang-1000.11.45.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file test.swift -target x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -color-diagnostics -module-name test -o /var/folders/fn/wh62twgj54180b7x1dx9j6080000gp/T/test-d0f7f4.o
0  swift                    0x000000010720964a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000107208dfe SignalHandler(int) + 302
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff7ac3ff5a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ffeec7e0000 _sigtramp + 1908015296
4  swift                    0x0000000103eef293 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtEmitter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 6531
5  swift                    0x0000000103ea826e swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 462
6  swift                    0x0000000103e0be14 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*)::$_1::operator()(swift::SILFunction*) const + 516
7  swift                    0x0000000103e0b142 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 1042
8  swift                    0x0000000103e1501b swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 939
9  swift                    0x0000000103e16bd5 swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional<unsigned int>, bool) + 1333
10 swift                    0x00000001034983fe performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 28990
11 swift                    0x000000010348ddc5 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7717
12 swift                    0x0000000103433a35 main + 1349
13 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff7a931015 start + 1
14 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000000f start + 2238509051
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file test.swift -target x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -color-diagnostics -module-name test -o /var/folders/fn/wh62twgj54180b7x1dx9j6080000gp/T/test-d0f7f4.o 
1.  While emitting SIL for 'runTest(success:failure:)' at test.swift:26:1
2.  While silgen emitFunction SIL function "@$S4test7runTest7success7failureyyAA8ResponseVc_ys5Error_pSgctF".
 for 'runTest(success:failure:)' at test.swift:26:1
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal 11 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it safe to assume that if I do not pass a capture block that the object will be retained when the closure is executed?

If I do the following, it compiles:

```
let uselessTempError = error
DispatchQueue.main.async { [err = uselessTempError] in
    failure(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `[err = error]` part. The following block will keep a strong reference to error:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    failure(error)
}
```

Comment: Yep, I am aware of that. I think I will post this on the swift forums as well as it looks like a compiler error to me. If do something like this var count = 0
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [err = error, count = count] in
            failure(err)
            count = count+1
        } it will work.

Comment: Well, any segmentation fault is a compiler bug. This should be handled gracefully if it truly is a problem, but in this case I don't see it.